# How can i access to this.files on v-on?

Tags: vue.js

Hello I am trying to update a photo with a onchange event i can do that with the following code:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="document.getElementById('i-logo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);"> <br />
```

But when try to use v-on like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" v-on:change="prepareLogo(files[0])"> <br />   

prepareLogo: function(a) {

  console.log(a)
```

I get the following error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null"

How can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass an argument to it. The event will be passed to your function automatically:

```
v-on:change="prepareLogo"

//

prepareLogo: function (e) // hydrated {
  console.log(e)
}
```